# How to concatenate JSX components in React Native

Tags: react-native, reactjs

For example, I wanna show a list of names. So I wanted to do something like this:

```js
var returnValue;
for (eachName of _names) {
  returnValue += (
  <TouchableHighlight
    onPress={() => this._onPressButton}>
      <Text>
      {eachName}
      </Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>);
}
return returnValue;
```

However, that is not valid. Which brings me to my question: How do I concatenate a dynamic amount of JSX components in React Native.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Figures I figure it out soon as I ask stackoverflow. The code needs to be put into an array:

```
var returnValue = [];
for (var i = 0; i < _names.length; i++) {

  returnValue.push(
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._onPressButton}>
      <Text>
      {_names[i]}
      </Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>);
}
return returnValue;
```

There is also more information here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children

Comment: awesome, thank you. I believe you may accept your answer instead, it's obviously the one people are looking for when coming to this question.

Comment: Well done. I would never think in an array of elements as a possible solution.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm receiving error: A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object. :(

Comment: I concatenated using `returnValue += ...` but that wouldn't work (on screen output would show something like [object]...). Fixed by using `returnValue.push( ...` as in this answer.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe a more elegant way:

```
return <View>
{_names.map((eachName) => {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._onPressButton}>
      <Text>
      {eachName}
      </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
})}
</View>
```

Comment: While I agree that this approach is commonplace, it is not capable of solving every problem (otherwise I wouldn't be here looking for alternatives)

Answer (score 0):

```
let returnValue = _names.map(eachName =>
 <TouchableHighlight
    onPress={() => this._onPressButton}>
      <Text>
      {eachName}
      </Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>);
return returnValue;
```